# Check if Express request data is array

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, express, body-parser

I've working on an Express 3.x API server (don't ask why I'm not upgrading to 4.x; I'm not in control of that), and I'm trying to implement support for batch requests for a particular endpoint. The endpoint currently supports regular requests (takes a JSON object), but I want it to also be able to take array of JSON objects, e.g.:

```
POST /api/posts
Body:
[
  { "title": "Hello World", "text": "blah blah" },
  { "title": "Hello World 2", "text": "blah blah blah" }
]
```

When I try to access the body of the request for a single request using `req.body`, I can retrieve the data just fine (it's just a regular JSON object). However, when I send an array, I find that the data gets parsed as an object of objects(?) instead of an array.

```
req.body = { "title": "Hello World", "text": "blah blah" };
typeof req.body;
// object
req.body.toString();
// [object Object]

req.body = [
  { "title": "Hello World", "text": "blah blah" },
  { "title": "Hello World 2", "text": "blah blah blah" }
];
typeof req.body;
// object
req.body.toString();
// [object Object],[object Object]
```

I tried using a simple check like this:

```
if (req.body.toString() !== '[object Object]') {
```

But an array containing only one object breaks this. E.g.:

```
req.body = [{ "title": "Hello World", "text": "blah blah" }];
typeof req.body;
// object
req.body.toString();
// [object Object]
```

Given this, is there guaranteed way to check to see if my data is an array?

Comment: if ( req.body instanceof Array ) {}

Comment: Array.isArray(req.body); also returns true

Comment: Well damn, why didn't I think of those... Many thanks, @CoryDanielson! If you can turn your comments into an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical way to do this in any JavaScript environment would be:

```
if ( req.body instanceof Array ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But since you have the luxury of your JavaScript running inside of [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29), you could also use the following without any issues:

```
if ( Array.isArray(req.body) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Just personal preference on which one you use.

Comment: Both solutions worked for me but I think the top solution is more readable. Does anyone know if there are superior performance benefits from using one over the other?

Comment: No there definitely isn't meaningful performance difference between the two. Unless you're doing something like running this code in a loop a million times, you wouldn't notice a difference.